# Getting history out of ammonite

Tags: scala, ammonite

What is the best way to print history of code executed in ammonite repl in previous sessions? I am aware of `repl.history` but it contains code from current session and I know that ammonite keeps history of previous sessions because snippets from them are available using "up arrow" key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux or Mac history is stored in your home directory in file `~/.ammonite/history`, so you could maybe just load it from file:

```
import scala.util.Using
import scala.io.Source

val history = Using(Source.fromFile("/path/to/home/.ammonite/history"))(_.getLines)
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly entries are not broken into sessions, but that's fine anyway!